# Connection failed using NSURLConnection , how to reconnect?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection

I turn off my network and run my ios program.
then stay stopping program.

after when I turn on my network. My program still stop.

I want to reconnect NSURLConnection in ios.

```
-(void) applistDBdownload
{
NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://sok129.cafxxx.com/oneapplist.sqlite3"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:file];

NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
connect= [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];

fileData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"fail");    -> come in when network off.
                   -> no come in when network on

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
          -> no come in when network on
          -> come in when network off 
}
```

1.How do I reconnect?

and

```
  - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
if(self.connect!=connection)
{
    NSLog(@"noconnect");
    return;
}


 [self.fileData appendData:data]; 
}
```

1. in this code area,if network turn off, how do i handling in this code?

Answer (score 0):

You should normally tell the user that something went wrong (using a `UIAlertView`, for example). You can ask the user to try to connect again. You can also, make this "transparent" to the user, and just try again without the user knowing what has happen. Just call your `applistDBdownload` again. Although, I think you should try to create some kind of logic to best suit your need (if you know your network is constantly going down, try 3 or 4 times, before warning the user). Lastly, you can try to change in the server side (probably receiving smaller packages, so the % of the network going down while you are receiving data is smaller).

Answer (score 0):

When your network is turn of, 
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
will get called here u can add a below line for requesting agin
[mConnection start]; 
When u start the connection and on mean while if u turn on the network, u can get proper connection.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Apple **MVCNetworking** which handle retrying HTTP requests. [MVCNetworking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MVCNetworking/Introduction/Intro.html)

The following one is a derived one from Apple : [MVCNetworking derived](https://github.com/acernikovs/MVCNetworking)

This kind of approach means that you should a bit more code at first when creating your request, but when the request fails, it will be given retries attempts for given intervals.